# Batch file rename based on pattern in bash

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

So I have a bunch of files named like this:

```
Movie Name Here [720p].mp4
```

And I want to rename them like this:

```
Movie Name.mp4
```

I have tried stuff like:

```
mv ./*\ [720p].mp4 ./*.mp4
```

But it doesn't work, for whatever reason. Any ideas on the quickest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to remove all ' [720p]':

```
rename 's/ \[720p\]//g' ./*
```

Comment: It's working exactly as **sed** (`man sed` for more details). after first **/** there is a pattern and after the second **/** the string to replace with (empty string in our case). And then we are asking to do it on every single file in current destination.